# Does NTEventLogAppender work on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: java, windows-server-2008, log4j

I can't find any reference to what versions of Windows the log4j NTEventLogAppender is supported on. I am specifically interested in whether it works on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NTEventLogAppender does work on Windows Server 2008. However, I was specifically interested in the 64-bit version and out of the box log4j does not support this. I had to use the code from the attachement on [this](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44386) log4j bug.

Comment: log4j 1.2.16 how includes 64-bit support for NTEventLogAppender.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [log4jna](http://log4jna.codeplex.com), an alternative implementation of NTEventLogAppender that doesn't require a native 32-bit vs. 64-bit DLL.